# Replacing an unknown pattern size with a character

Tags: java, regex

Is there a way to replace  a specific repetitive character using regular expressions?

Example:

> str = "Anne has nnnn things"

The solution would be:

> "Ane has n things"

If a string has two or more instances of one character next to each other, the regular expression should replace them all with just one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible:

```
inputString.replaceAll("(.)\\1+", "$1")
```

Match one character, capture it, repeat it once or more, replace with only the capture.

However this may not be the faster solution. Such a thing is also doable with a simple loop:

```
public String removeRepetitions(final String input)
{
    if (input.isEmpty())
        return input;

    final int len = input.length();
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(length);

    char current = input.charAt(0);
    char c;
    sb.append(current);

    for (int i = 1; i < len; i++) {
        c = input.charAt(i);
        if (c != current) {
            sb.append(c);
            current = c;
        }
    }

    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I will modify this and try to solve my specific need

Answer (score 1):

This should match n that repeats 2 or more times:

```
/n{2,}/
```

Comment: that didnt work for me. String str = "A_Sommmmething";  str=str.replaceAll("/m{2,}/","_"); got the same thing